# How do I install rgdal in r for mac?

Tags: r, rgdal

I got this error...

library(rgdal)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in get(method, envir = envir):
lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal/R/rgdal.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(method, envir = envir) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

I don't know what to do, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: not sure what your use case is and I'm not  mac user, but I will mention that rgdal is close to obsolete, and most likely you are better off using a newer package.  E.g. see https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html

Comment: What happens if you try to reinstall with: `install.packages("rgdal", type="binary")`.  I don't know if it makes a difference but please clarify whether this is a intel Mac or Apple silicon.  Also assuming current version of R?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.